# mono for android: Update a data on a list

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin.android

In my application, I display a list of contacts with their name, picture, and presence status. 
The application receives an event every time a contact changes his presence, and what I am trying to do is to update the list with the contact's new presence.

This is how I bind my list to a custom list adapter:

```
 ListView listView; 
 listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List); 
 listView.Adapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, names);
```

And this is a part of the GetView of my ContactListAdapter

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        { 
            var item = this.contacts.ElementAt(position); 
            var view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available 
           // if (view == null || !(convertView is LinearLayout)) // otherwise create a new one 
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.contactItemView, parent, false); 
            var p = context; 
            var imageItem = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.presence) as ImageView; 

          string status = null; 
            foreach (CPresenceInfo pres in item.Presences) 
            { 
                if (pres.Type.ToString().Equals("TWS")) status = pres.StatusBusy; 
            } 
            if (status != null) 
            { 
                if (status.Equals("ONLINE")) imageItem.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.online); 
                if (status.Equals("BUSY")) imageItem.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.busy); 
                if (status.Equals("ABSENT")) imageItem.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.absent); 
                if (status.Equals("OFFLINE")) imageItem.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.offline); 

            } 
            return status; 

            return view; 
        } 



// And the method that receives the event: 
        void CEventParser_OnPresenceChangedEvent(string personGuid, CPresenceInfo presence) 
        { 
                //Update the contact row or the entire list?? 
        }
```

I don't know if I can update just one row in the list, or if I have to update the entire list. But in both cases I don't know how to do... 
I know there is a `NotifyDataSetChanged()` method but I don't know how and where to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updating all items

You can do this by just using the NotifyDataSetChanged method after the new data is available - this will trigger the listview to completely redraw itself. It will make new requests in to your adapter to do this.

#### Updating contents within one item

One way to do this is to keep a record of which views are currently being used for which records.

Obviously you have to be careful to remember that views get reused as the list scrolls.

If you keep track of the current view-item mapping, then it's relatively simple to update the current view each time.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I have looked a little further into the NotifyDataSetChanged method and figured out how to apply it to my list. The user needs to scroll the list to update it but that's enough for now.
Do you have an example of how to apply your method to update contents within one item?